# Highcharts: show data labels as relative value (percentage) on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a bar chart with a hover effect using Highcharts software. The chart should look like this: http://www.computerbase.de/2016-02/directx-12-benchmarks-ashes-of-the-singularity-beta/#diagramm-ashes-of-the-singularity-1920-1080

As you can see the data label values change into percentages once you hover the chart, showing the relative values.

Creating the chart itself is not the issue. Changing the data labels however is. How can I loop over all data labels, calculate the relative value and update the labels? The [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver) does not say much.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        // change text of all data labels
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log(this.chart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Really seems like a [vampire question](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) to me.. have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can't find anything in the API. I also did `console.log(this);` and looked at the methods in the chart object, though there's nothing in it to access all data labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do [`Series.setData()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) with data that has new labels set on `mouseOver` event of point. Use `dataLabels` `format` option to get labels from point data and `key` setting in your series to set label info.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pov2dt0q/

```
$(function() {
  var startingData = [
      [1, '1'],
      [2, '2'],
      [3, '3']
    ],
    percentData = [
      [
        [1, 'x 100%'],
        [2, '200%'],
        [3, '300%']
      ],
      [
        [1, '50%'],
        [2, 'x 100%'],
        [3, '150%']
      ],
      [
        [1, '33%'],
        [2, '66%'],
        [3, 'x 100%']
      ]
    ];
  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      type: 'bar',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -5,
        format: '{point.label}'
      },
      data: $.extend([], startingData),
      keys: ['y', 'label'],
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            this.series.setData(percentData[this.x]);
          },
          mouseOut: function() {
            this.series.setData(startingData);
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
chart.tooltip.options.formatter = function() {
    var xyArr=[];
    $.each(this.points,function(){
        xyArr.push('Serie: ' + this.series.name + ', ' +'X: ' + this.x + ', Y: ' +this.y);
    });
    return xyArr.join('<br/>');
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/zAGGT/